# NFS: Permissions to write/create?

Tags: nfs

I have setup a server and client (both LinuxMint 21.3) with NFS so that the client should have read-write access.  However, it successfully reads but cannot write.  I've searched through lots of questions here and elsewhere but not seen anything that seems to clearly provide a solution.  I've ran through this [page](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-configure-a-nfs-server-and-mount-nfs-shares-on-ubuntu-18.04/) which confirmed what I have done.

Here's the setup:

Server `/etc/exports` is set for read/write:

```
/exports  192.168.0.0/28(rw,no_subtree_check)
```

Client `/etc/fstab` is set to mount at boot:

```
media:/exports /mnt/nfs/media-server  nfs      auto,noatime,defaults,x-gvfs-show    0       0
```

Permissions on the server exports (selecting just one directory for this example):

```
root@media:~# ls -al /exports/Software
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 28 11:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Mar 28 11:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 28 11:56 Linux
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 28 11:56 Windows
```

Permissions on the client mounts:

```
root@brawn:~# ls -al /mnt/nfs/media-server/Software
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 28 11:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Mar 28 11:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 28 11:56 Linux
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 28 11:56 Windows
```

But attempts to copy from the client to the server -- or to create a folder on the server from the client -- fail.

Attempting to copy as my user (which has the same uid, gid on both systems)

```
:~$ cp /media/<user>/Storage/Software/Linux/zoom*.deb /mnt/nfs/media-server/Software/Linux
cp: cannot create regular file '/mnt/nfs/media-server/Software/Linux/zoom_amd64.deb': Permission denied
```

Even trying as root fails:

```
:~# cp /media/<user>/Storage/Software/Linux/zoom_amd64.deb /mnt/nfs/media-server/Software/Linux
cp: cannot create regular file '/mnt/nfs/media-server/Software/Linux/zoom_amd64.deb': Permission denied
```

**UPDATE**

Using info provided in @vidarlo's answer, I did the following:

On the server:

```
sudo groupadd -g 1003 nfsshare
sudo usermod -a -G nfsshare <user>
cd /exports
sudo chgrp -R nfsshare /exports
sudo chmod -R 775 /exports
sudo exportfs -ar
```

On the client:

```
sudo groupadd -g 1003 nfsshare
sudo usermod -a -G nfsshare <user>
mount -a
```

My user now has full access to the exported contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it fails as user because the folder is owned by `root`, and only `root` has write permissions.

Second, it fails for `root` because NFS doesn't trust `root` on remote systems by default.

You have two choices:

1. Give users access by a combination of changing owner and permissions
2. Export the directory with [`no_root_squash`-option](https://serverfault.com/questions/1089557/what-does-the-no-all-squash-option-do-in-nfs-exports) to give root full permissions.

The latter is [not a good idea from a security perspective](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html/security_guide/s2-server-nfs-noroot) - at least not without any further actions, as it will allow remote root to create suid binaries on the server...

Comment: So, create a separate network user that would be used for that purpose and add that user to both the server and client(s) with the same uid/gid.  Is that correct?

Comment: Or, maybe a network group to which I would add my user?

Comment: NFS works by UID and GID, yes. How you solve that is up to you.